Unity Editor Api for scriptable object apply on Edit Mode
So i want to design an editor which has the following requirements.
Suppose i already have a prefab called Player.prefab and script attached as Player.cs
And have a scriptable object called PlayerSettings1. So three components,

Player.prefab
Player.cs
PlayerSettings1.cs

Suppose the scriptable object has the fields as.
PlayerSettings

[Text] Name - John
[int] Health - 100
[Imagereference]Face - Sprite
[Shader] complexion - fair

Now in edit mode i want to test multiple scriptable objects, on the prefab.
So suppose we have multiple scriptable of the same type PlayerSettings1, PlayerSettings2, PlayerSettings3, and PlayerSettings4.
So how can i create a custom Unity editor, So that when i drag and place the scriptable object, i can visually see the effect on the prefab. I am able to achieve in play mode, as based on my business logic, and load the any of the scriptable object, and pass to the Player setup(PlayerSettings settings) function to set the fields based on settings, How can i achieve in edit mode the same functionality.

able to achieve in play mode, as based on my business logic, and load the any of the scriptable object do you need other scripts available or is all the information needed on your player object. And why can't you make a simple test scene where you switch around your components compared to trying to get everything running in editor mode?

What code are you using to apply the change at runtime? The code for doing it in editor should be very similar. What part do you find is not working at present?

means i am not aware of the Unity Editor, on how can i achieve this. So wanted to know an algorithm, with Unity Editor defined API's.
